# Matlab fints doesn't like a string value I pass as an argument

Tags: string, matlab

I have a program that takes the columns of a fints-object, multiplies them together pairwise in all combinations and output the result in a new fints object. I have the code for the data, but I also want the series labels to carry through so that the product of column a and b has label a*b.

```
function tsB = MulTS(tsA)
    anames = fieldnames(tsA,1)';
    A = fts2mat(tsA);
    [i,j] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2),1:size(A,2));
    B = Mul(A(:,i(:)),A(:,j(:)));
    q = [anames(:,i(:)); anames(:,j(:))];
    bnames = strcat(q(1,:),'*', q(2,:));
    tsB=fints(tsA.dates, B, bnames);
end
```

I get warnings when I run it.

```
tsA= fints([1 2 3]', [[1 1 1]' [2 2 2]'],{'a','b'}');
MulTS(tsA)
??? Error using ==> fints.fints at 188
Illegal name(s) detected. Please check the name(s).

Error in ==> MulTS at 10
    tsB=fints(tsA.dates, B, bnames);"
```

It seems Matlab doesn't like the format of bnames. I've tried googling stuff like "convert cell array to string matlab" and trying things like b = {bnames}. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to acces to the string into a cell array ?

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem (see my answer)?  Also, I'd suggest renaming your question title to start "MATLAB fints ..." so it is easier to find for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `datanames` (`bnames` in `MulTS`) seems to contain a "*" character, which is illegal according to [`fints` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/fints.html):

> datanames
>
> Cell array of data series names. Overrides the default data series names. Default data series names are series1, series2, and so on.
>
> Note:   Not all strings are accepted as datanames parameters. Supported data series names cannot start with a number and must contain only these characters:
>
> - Lowercase Latin alphabet, a to z
> - Uppercase Latin alphabet, A to Z
> - Underscore, _

Try replacing the "*" with "_" or something else.